# How can I dynamically create a ProfileView for each user by clicking on their username (Vaadin 23)

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin, user-profile

First the technical details:
Coding in Java, IntelliJ, with Springboot and Vaadin23.

Hey guys, I am currently working on a Web Application Project where I have a movie database and a social network of users. (It is like a social network for rating movies and getting information about movies etc) Every user has a ID, username, name etc. And of course I have implemented such things as userService, userRepository etc. Everything is working and connected to my database.

I have a ProfileView that shows the profile of the user currently logged in with "authenticateduser", so far, but I want to edit the ProfileView so that it can show the profile of every other user as well.

To be more specific I want to do the following:
I have a SearchView with a grid where I can find all users. (works already) In this grid I can click on a Button which should lead me to the individual ProfileView of this specific user.

The grid is working, the button already exists but has no function yet.

I thought about trying it with URL Templates an beforeenterevent, to create a individual URL for every ProfileView for each user. But the documentation on the official vaadin page is not really helpful for my specific problem.

Anyone has an idea how to get this done and what to try? I really don't have an idea how to approach this, sorry If the question is not specific enough. Screenshots of my ProfileView and SearchView are attached.

This is the first part of my SearchView Class:

```
@Route(value = "searchUser", layout = MainLayout.class)
@PageTitle("Search User")
@PermitAll
@Uses(Icon.class)
```

public class SearchView extends VerticalLayout {

```
Grid<User> grid = new Grid<>(User.class);
TextField filterText = new TextField();

private final UserService userService;
private AuthenticatedUser authenticatedUser;

public SearchView(UserService userService, AuthenticatedUser authenticatedUser) {
    this.userService = userService;
    this.authenticatedUser = authenticatedUser;
    addClassName("Search-View");
    setSizeFull();
    configureGrid();

    add(getToolbar(), grid);
    updateList();
}


private void configureGrid() {
    grid.addClassNames("user-grid");
    grid.setSizeFull();
    grid.setColumns("username", "name");
    grid.addColumn(
            new ComponentRenderer<>(Button::new, (button, UI) -> {
                button.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_ICON,
                        ButtonVariant.LUMO_ERROR,
                        ButtonVariant.LUMO_TERTIARY);
                button.addClickListener(e -> switchTo());
                button.setIcon(new Icon(VaadinIcon.USER_CARD));
            })).setHeader("View profile");
```

This is my ProfileView Class:

```
@Route(value = "ProfileView", layout = MainLayout.class)
@PageTitle("Profile Page")
@PermitAll
@Uses(Icon.class)
```

public class ProfileView extends VerticalLayout {

```
private final AuthenticatedUser authenticatedUser;
private UserService userService;

Grid<User> grid = new Grid<>(User.class);

private TextField firstName = new TextField("First name");
private TextField lastName = new TextField("Last name");
private EmailField email = new EmailField("Email address");

private Button watchedMovies = new Button("See watched Movies");
private Button watchList = new Button("See Watchlist");
private Button seeFriends = new Button("See Friends");
private Button privacy = new Button("Privacy Settings");


private Binder<User> binder = new Binder<>(User.class);

public ProfileView(UserService userService, AuthenticatedUser authenticatedUser) {
    this.userService = userService;
    this.authenticatedUser = authenticatedUser;



    addClassName("profile-view");
    add(createTitle());
    add(createFormLayout());
    add(createButtonLayout());

    binder.bindInstanceFields(this);
    clearForm();

   firstName.setValue(authenticatedUser.get().get().getFirstname());
   lastName.setValue(authenticatedUser.get().get().getLastname());
   email.setValue(authenticatedUser.get().get().getEmail());

}

private void clearForm() {
    binder.setBean(new User());
}

private Component createTitle() {
    return new H3("Personal information of " + authenticatedUser.get().get().getFirstname());
}

private Component createFormLayout() {
    FormLayout formLayout = new FormLayout();
    formLayout.add(firstName, lastName, email);
    return formLayout;
}

private Component createButtonLayout() {
    HorizontalLayout buttonLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
    buttonLayout.addClassName("button-layout");
    watchedMovies.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY);
    watchList.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY);
    seeFriends.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY);
    privacy.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_SUCCESS);

    //TODO switch MovieListView to WatchList and switch to personalized page
    watchedMovies.addClickListener(e -> UI.getCurrent().navigate(WatchedMoviesView.class));
    watchList.addClickListener((e -> UI.getCurrent().navigate(Watchlist.class)));
    seeFriends.addClickListener(e -> UI.getCurrent().navigate(FriendlistView.class));
    privacy.addClickListener(e-> UI.getCurrent().navigate(PrivacyView.class));

    buttonLayout.add(watchedMovies);
    buttonLayout.add(watchList);
    buttonLayout.add(seeFriends);
    buttonLayout.add(privacy);
    return buttonLayout;
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

You can parameterize views/routes via the URL.  Check the docs about
[Routing and URL
parameters](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/routing/tutorial-router-url-parameters):

```java
@Route(value = "user/profile")
public class PublicUserProfileView extends Div implements HasUrlParameter<String> {
    @Override
    public void setParameter(BeforeEvent event, String username) {
        setText(String.format("User profile for %s!", username));
    }
}
```

Then from your grid you can use `UI.navigate` to pass down the username.

As a random side note: I'd separate the views for the "public profile"
and "my profile" just to be on the safe side.  If only for the ability
to allow the currently logged in user to preview their public profile.